# How to apply dark theme in whole spyder3

Tags: themes, spyder

tools->preferences->syntax coloring->scheme  only change the color in editor,

so it looks like this, 
[image]

I want know how to apply dark theme in whole spyder3

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thank you, I have solved this problem,

1. pip install qdarkstyle
2. go to: https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/2350
3. Ctrl + F app.set

hope you can also make it and waiting for spyder 4, which may contain official solutions.

---

Update in 22/11/18,
I have noticed that the official solution in spyder 4 is avaiable!
[image]

Answer (score 3):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) Syntax coloring for the IPython console was added in Spyder **3.2**, released in July/2017. If you're not seeing it in your current setup, it means you are using an old Spyder version and you need to update it.